# A Numerical Sequences proof.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials

Let $ 0<a<1 $ be a real number, and let $ a_n \in \left ( -1,0 \right )$ defined by the relation $ \sqrt[n]{a} = 1+a_n$ ,   $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Show the following inequality:

$ |a_n| \le \frac{1}{n} \bigl( \frac{1-a}{a}\bigr)$,    $ n \ge 1$.

This problem was proposed by my professor of Mathematical Analysis $2$. The following is my personal solution, different from the one expected.

Comment: I am fairly sure that I saw the identical question (and answer) yesterday. Did you delete and re-post it?

Comment: Yes, yesterday I posted the same but I did a mistake of transcription in the solution and when I corrected it a lot of minutes passed. Maybe people who already red it skipped it because of that mistake. So the post was ignored and lost in the sea of Question section, because of nobody interacted with it. I believed that there could be more interaction about it so I wanted to propose it one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis it's $ \sqrt[n]{a} = 1 + a_n$ , in particular $ a_n=\sqrt[n]{a}-1<0$ $\to$ $|a_n|=1-\sqrt[n]{a}$.

Second member can be viewed as a division of polynomials:

$$ 1 - \sqrt[n]{a} = \frac{1 - a}{1 + \sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{a^2} + \sqrt[n]{a^3} + ... +\sqrt[n]{a^{n-1}} }$$

Note that terms in denominator,

$$1 + \sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{a^2} + \sqrt[n]{a^3} + ... +\sqrt[n]{a^{n-1}}$$

are all $\ge$ $a$: being $ 0<a<1$, indeed, elevating $a$ to an exponent $ \in \left [ 0,1 \right]$ (note that exponents of $ a$ in denominator are $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{2}{n}$, ... , $\frac{n-1}{n} \le 1$) will get a value  $\ge a$, i.e. closer to $1$.
There are $n$ terms in denominator (note that all powers of $ a $ from $0$ to $ n-1 $ are present, and $ n-1+1=n$).                                              Then it's

$$ |a_n| = 1 - \sqrt[n]{a} = \frac{1 - a}{1 + \sqrt[n]{a} + \sqrt[n]{a^2} + \sqrt[n]{a^3} + ... +\sqrt[n]{a^{n-1}} } \le \frac{1-a}{na}$$

from which follows: $ |a_n| \le \frac{1}{n} \bigl( \frac{1-a}{a} \bigr)$

$\square$

Comment: Do you want a different solution?

Comment: It would be welcome!

Comment: @VIVID I believe that your solution was correct: Bernoulli's inequality is valid $\forall$ positive exponent, so also for $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Eigenket, I undeleted the post to see. As @Empy2 mentioned, the inequality goes the other way since $0 \le 1/n \le  1$

Comment: @VIVID You're right, thank you. But I believe that there should be a correct way to use Bernoulli's inequality, because I remember my professor wrote to use it as an hint.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, there should be. You can play a bit with some substitutions to make the inequality handy as I tried (unsuccessfully)